# displaying an image in colab

Tags: python, image-processing, google-colaboratory

I'm typing this code in google colab :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

img = cv2.imread('/gdrive/My Drive/plant.jpg')
cv2_imshow(img)
```

and it generates this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-5fed60b4be52> in <module>()
      5 
      6 img = cv2.imread('/gdrive/My Drive/plant.jpg',0)
----> 7 cv2_imshow(img)
      8 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/patches/__init__.py in cv2_imshow(a)
     16       image.
     17   """
---> 18   a = a.clip(0, 255).astype('uint8')
     19   # cv2 stores colors as BGR; convert to RGB
     20   if a.ndim == 3:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clip'
```

Comment: img = cv2.imread(r'C:\gdrive\My Drive\plant.jpg')

Comment: Have a look here at how to [edit] your question... https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: file's not there. it's that simple. ignore the first comment that suggests backslashes... because we aren't on windows here

Answer (score -1):

Solution code:

```
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('/content/hand.jpg')

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: that's **not a solution**. exchanging imshow for plotting doesn't fix the fact that the **file could not be read/found**. why do you assume that `/content/hand.jpg` even exists on OP's colab instance, or that OP would want that file? the question contains a **different** path. -- perhaps review [answer] -- please slow down with your low-quality shotgun answering. or at least stick to questions that are _not_ tagged with special-interest topics (which attract competent specialists that *will* point out issues in your answers)

Comment: this is nothing like shotgun just execute code in your google colab and you find how output is generated. And apart from that for code simulation i use that hand example and one more thing this same problem i have found in one of my project and i solve it by this way.